# How to print the calling method name and line number for Deprecation Warning message in python?

Tags: python, deprecated

My deprecate warning message is in a function. I would like to print out the module name and line number of the calling function so that I can easily locate them. Take `open()` for example:

```
/path/to/file/group.py:180: DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated 
with open(tmpName, 'rU') as csvfile
```

However, my own warning prints like this:

```
/path/to/file/models.py:735: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated. Use course_id instead! 
warnings.warn("Deprecated. Use course_id instead!", DeprecationWarning)
```

On line 735 of `models.py` is where the `warnings.warn()` call is located. Is there a way to make the warning output the parent caller's name and line number? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control which caller you want the warning to apply to by using the `stacklevel` argument.

For instance, the following code:

```
import warnings

def hello(s):
    if isinstance(s, int):
        deprecation('Use of integers is deprecated.')
    else:
        print(s)

def deprecation(msg):
    warnings.warn(msg, DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=3)

hello(1)
```

Will give the following warning:

```
warning_test.py:12: DeprecationWarning: Use of integers is deprecated.
  hello(1)
```

See: [Python documentation on `warnings.warn`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn)

Comment: Aha! I was too focused on the doc of DeprecationWarning, instead of warn(). Thanks!